# Can't access AWS billing data although I have full permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In my AWS account I created a user and gave it full permissions using the `AdministratorAccess` policy. That's the document for the policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Still, when I login using this user, I can't see my billing information. It says I don't have the permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the AWS billing data is only accessible to the root account and not subject to IAM. In order to share access the root account has to go to the "Account Stettings" and enable "IAM User Access to Billing Information".

Comment: Yep. There are several instances of IAM permissions that must be *explicitly* granted because they are not included in `*`.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Could you mention other such cases? So I would avoid them beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

In case this question is interesting to anyone else - according to Perplexity.AI there are, in fact, only 3 policies that are not included by default in the `AdministratorAccess` group. They are:

1. Billing
2. Support
3. ViewOnlyAccess

These need to be enabled separately by the root user for all AIM Admin identities. However - while they are all listed as "permissions", `ViewOnlyAccess` is actually a restriction (that prevents the user from doing anything other than viewing, as the name suggests) so it's entirely reasonable not to have that policy attached by default to an "admin" user.

Oh, and *obviously* that's not all you need to do... you then have to follow the advice on this page to enable it https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/iam-billing-access
And then pray to a Greek or Egyptian deity of your choice.
And then it will work... maybe.